# loop statement in javascript not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript

The below code will only execute the alert statement statement once then break. For example i = 2000 i was expecting it to be printed 4 times will it reaches the condition.

```
var i = str.value;

for (i; i <= 2400; i += 100) {
    alert(i);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the type of `str.value` is a string, then it execute for the first time, the next time it will fail, because

```
i += 100
```

will concatenate `100` as a string to `2000`, instead of adding. You can check that like this

```
console.log('2000' + 100);
# 2000100
```

which will be greater than 2400

```
console.log('2000100' > 2400);
# true
```

So, you should be converting `i` to an integer, like this

```
var i = parseInt(str.value, 10);
```

with that change, the output becomes

```
2000
2100
2200
2300
2400
```